# How to get Excel Graph to ignore cells containing formulas?

Tags: excel, excel-2013

How can I get the graph to ignore the cells that contain blanks?

The formula used for the cells is as follows:

=IF('PivotCL 30+'!I5="","",'PivotCL 30+'!I5/'PivotCL 30+'!$G5)

Thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick & dirty approach would be to return `NA()` instead of an empty string `""` in your formula:

`=IF('PivotCL ... = "", NA() ,'PivotCL ...)`

If your goal is to keep the data presentable, you could consider a conditional formatting with white font-color and Formula `ISNA(...)=TRUE`.

Comment: Already tried that, but then I would have #N/As on all the empty cells.

Comment: Hm. If your goal is to keep the data presentable, you could consider a conditional formatting with white font-color and Formula "ISNA(..)"=TRUE.

Comment: The N/A approach combined with conditional formatting worked like wonders. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, provided you don't mention I  encouraged you to use formulas and conditional formatting at all, which is reasonably quick but unreasonable dirty ;)